# Can blender render result make an object always in front rendering

Tags: rendering

I can't use the "in front" option because I need my results from the render and not the 3D editor. How can I render an object always in front of the other objects in the Blender render.

Answer (score 5):

The only way i know is using compositing.

So you make two scenes, one with your object only, one with the "rest" and then you combine those two in compositing:

[image]

[image]